# Azure IoT Hub receiving messages late

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

In our IoT Solution that utilizes Azure IoT Hub on server side and Azure IoT Client SDK on Device side, we are seeing intermittent delay in time between device sent a status message over MQTT and message was received by IoT Hub.

In some cases, we are seeing 62 seconds when IoT Hub enqueued the message.

For example, below for Message Id: 5cfbe0ac-d987-3317-bda6-f63ec5fe562a

T1-T0 = 62 seconds

Device Timestamp (T0) =  2017-12-13T12:31:12

IoT hub Timestamp(T1) = 2017-12-13T12:32:14.3600000Z

**Question:**

1. What could be the reason for this delay in message reaching to IoT Hub?
2. How can we dig further (add logs in inner component to figure out where exactly the latency is)?
3. Any suggestions?

Sample IoT Hub queued Message:

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "attributes":[  
         {  
            "code":"STS",
            "value":"1",         }
      ],
      "type":"status"
   },
   "messageid":"5cfbe0ac-d987-3317-bda6-f63ec5fe562a",
   "protocol":"MQTT",
   "**DeviceTimestamp**":"1513168272",
   "EventProcessedUtcTime":"2017-12-13T12:32:14.0683721Z",
   "PartitionId":5,
   "EventEnqueuedUtcTime":"2017-12-13T12:32:14.3010000Z",
   "IoTHub":{  
      "MessageId":null,
      "CorrelationId":null,
      "**EnqueuedTime**":"2017-12-13T12:32:14.3600000Z",
      "StreamId":null
   }
}
```

Update: Device is using Azure Client SDK version 1.1.27. The device code is in C language. The device is not behind firewall or any special network topology used, it connects to the IoT Hub via MQTT. The delay is observed when the status messages is sent over MQTT.

Update 2: Device adds timestamp into message before sending it using Azure client SDK method. The timestamp matches in most cases except when we see spike e.g. above message. It calculates timestamp using NTP time server and send as EPOCH. The IoT hub is on higher tier (10 units).

Based on our analysis today, we are suspecting the Azure client SDK. Our hypothesis is, we believe the SDK store the messages internally (in a list or queue) while trying to establish a connection with IoT Hub. If it does not connect to IoT Hub, it retries after few seconds. When it restore the connection, it delivers the message stored in its queue (again when the message were delayed we saw a bunch of messages coming together with same delay, that kind of prove this hypothesis).

Comment: Can you please add some more details such as the language you are using on the device side, a code snippet maybe, Network configuration the device is behind ...

Comment: @OlivierBloch - Added some more details. The code is as per the samples provided on GitHub for using Azure Client SDK.

Comment: How accurate is the device timestamp? Is this a free IoT Hub or a higher tier?

Comment: Device add timestamp into message before sending it using Azure client SDK method. It calculates timestamp using NTP time server and send as EPOCH. The IoT hub is on higher tier (10 units).

Comment: @SBirthare, could you please tell me how and when calculate the **DeviceTimestamp** before sending the message.I am a little confused about that, i calculated the T0 by adding the timestamp 1513168272 as ticks based on current date, the result is 12:02:31.Am i right in this way?If not, please tell me how to calculate the T0 and what is the baseline of DeviceTimestamp.

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT - Use https://www.epochconverter.com/ to convert EPOCH to datetime. The value will be "Wednesday, December 13, 2017 12:31:12 PM" UTC. Where as IoT Hub Enqueue time is "2017-12-13T12:32:14.3600000Z".

Comment: @SBirthare,could you provide the NTP server address and code snippet?I have tested the sample without NTP,the delay of the message is less then 2 seconds.

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue. Have you resolved this? Please help me

Comment: Do you guys have any update for this ?